# Retrieve results from nested array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I can't understand how to pull the results out. I keep get "Array", "Array" with those echo statements. Thanks

```
$qry  = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE installation_id = $installation_id";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qry) or die('-1'.mysqli_error($mysqli));

$categories = array();
while ($row_rsCategories = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
    $product_array = array();
    $product_array_query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT id, user_id, client_id, comments, stars FROM reviews WHERE user_id = '".$row_rsCategories['userId']."'");

    while($product_array_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($product_array_query)) {
       $product_array[] = array(
           "id" => $product_array_fetch['user_id'],
           "name" => $product_array_fetch['comments']
       );
    }                

    $categories[] = array(
        'id' => $row_rsCategories['userId'],
        'name' => $row_rsCategories['userName'],
        'products' => $product_array,
    );
}

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category['name'];
    echo $category['products'];
}
```

UPDATE:

I found one error in calling usersName. So now it prints out both users name together.

The Catergory array is:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 63
    [name] => Paul Rothlisberger
    [products] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Comment: `echo(array)` will show `Array`. try `print_r` or `var_dump();`

Comment: What do you get, if you try `print_r($category)`?

Comment: @andy updated questions with information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Array" is printed because that is the string representation of the array `$category['products']`. To print all information for each product in a comma separated list, use:

```
foreach($category['products'] as $product) {
    echo implode(",", $product);
}
```

In other words, you have to iterate over each element in the array down to single values in the innermost array.

UPDATE: Missed the fact, that your products are also arrays. Updated the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Even with that I still get "Lauren Array,ArrayPaul " Those are the two users and the first one is the only one that has a products. I need to print out each of these Users separately.

Comment: Updated the answer. Sorry I missed the additional array since the example of 'Paul' in the question did not contain another array.

Comment: Huge help. Thanks so much.